# I need to use a function in order to get a return instead printing the output

Tags: python

A catering company has hired you to help with organizing and preparing customer's orders. You are given a list of each customer's desired items, and must write a program that will count the number of each items needed for the chefs to prepare. The items that a customer can order are: salad, hamburger, and water.

Write a function called item_order that takes as input a string named order. The string contains only words for the items the customer can order separated by one space. The function returns a string that counts the number of each item and consolidates them in the following order: salad:[# salad] hamburger:[# hambruger] water:[# water]

If an order does not contain an item, then the count for that item is 0.

Notice that each item is formatted as [name of the item][a colon symbol][count of the item] and all item groups are separated by a space.

For example:

• If order = "salad water hamburger salad hamburger" then the function returns "salad:2 hamburger:2 water:1"
• If order = "hamburger water hamburger" then the function returns "salad:0 hamburger:2 water:1"

This is the code so far:

```
s = '"hamburger water hamburger water salad "'
#The value of s will be received by the user only with the options in s

subs = 'salad'

count =0
flag=True
start=0
while flag:
    a = s.find(subs,start)  

    if a==-1:          
        flag=False
    else:               
        count+=1        
        start=a+1
if count==0:
    salad="salad:0"
else:    
        b=str(count)   
        c=subs+':'
        salad=c+b 


subs = 'water'

count =0
flag=True
start=0
while flag:
    a = s.find(subs,start)  

    if a==-1:          
        flag=False
    else:               
        count+=1        
        start=a+1
if count==0:
    water="water:0"
else:      

        b=str(count)   
        c=subs+':'
        water=c+b 



subs = 'hamburger'


count =0
flag=True
start=0
while flag:
    a = s.find(subs,start)  

    if a==-1:          
        flag=False
    else:               
        count+=1        
        start=a+1
if count==0:
    hamburger="hamburger:0"
else:
        b=str(count)   
        c=subs+':'
        hamburger=c+b 


print salad,hamburger,water
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906570/counting-and-grouping-with-python/34906936#34906936

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def item_order(order):
    new_order = order.split()
    sal = 0
    wat = 0
    hum = 0
    for a in range(len(new_order)):
        if new_order[a] == 'salad':
            sal = sal + 1
        elif new_order[a] == 'water':
            wat = wat + 1
        elif new_order[a] == 'hamburger':
            hum = hum + 1

    return ('salad:' + str(sal) + ' ' + 'hamburger:' + str(hum) + ' ' +'water:'   + str(wat))
```

Comment: Rushik Thumar it work like a charm thanks for your help really appreciated